# Как найти элемент по значению свойства в Битрикс?

Tags: битрикс

Есть инфоблок с подрядчиками, где заведены свойства Наименование, Е-mail и т.д.

Нужно, имея email, получить наименование.
Видимо, нужно в $arFilter поместить его, но даже не знаю, как именуется это свойство.

Как это сделать?

```
    $arSelect = array();
    $arFilter = Array(
        "IBLOCK_ID" => 52,
        "ACTIVE_DATE"=>"Y",
        "ACTIVE"=>"Y"
    );
    $res = CIBlockElement::GetList(Array(), $arFilter, false, "", $arSelect);
    $conractors = array();
    while($ob = $res->GetNextElement()){
        $arFields = $ob->GetFields();
        $conractors[$arFields['ID']] = $arFields['NAME'];
    }
```

Такой код выводит наименования.

Comment: Если ответ на вопрос был исчерпывающим, пожалуйста, подтвердите его как решенный.

Answer (score 0):

Если элемент добавлен как свойство инфоблока с именем EMAIL, то:

```
$arFilter = Array(
    "IBLOCK_ID" => 52,
    "ACTIVE_DATE"=>"Y",
    "ACTIVE"=>"Y",
    "PROPERTY_EMAIL" => "abcd@bla-bla.ru"
);
```

Comment: Все-равно выдает всех подрядчиков, а нужен только один, у которого такой e-mail. Видимо, поле называется не "PROPERTY_EMAIL". А как узнать название поля для e-mail?

Comment: Иными словами, нужно найти элемент по значению свойства.

Comment: В админке надо посмотреть как называется поле

Comment: Рабочий стол -> Контент -> Инфоблоки -> Типы инфоблоков -> "Ваш тип инфоблоков" -> "Ваш инфоблок"

на вашем инфоблоке жмите редактировать затем вкладка "Свойства" там вы увидите код нужного свойства для использования в фильтре. Но учтите что в фильтре у свойств обязательна приставка PROPERTY_ ТУТ КОД